# Google Maps not Showing in QGIS 2.12

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, google-maps, openlayers-2, quickmapservices

The Google Maps in my OpenLayers plugin in QGIS 2.12 does not show anymore. The other maps do show, that is:

- OSM
- Bing
- MapQuest
- Stamen
- Apple Maps

I tried in QGIS 2.8 and Google Maps does not show there either. This is the case in both my home and work computers, which are on different networks. Did the Google Maps go away?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quick Map Services is build upon OpenLayers plugin (using github). The biggest difference is that Quick Map Services uses tile servers and not the direct api for getting google layers via OpenLayers which causes zoom errors,... give Quick Map Services a try.

How to get the Google Layers activated: go to Quick Map Services -> Settings -> select the tab 'contributed services' and press 'Get contributed pack'. When you now go to Q.M.S. your list of available layers is extended.

Answer (score 13):

I suggest you drop the OpenLayers plugin for background maps and try the Quick Map Services plugin instead.

It has more layers than OpenLayers, seems more robust, directly accesses map tiles rather than using OpenLayers' JavaScript to get them, lines up properly on Composer maps, etc.

I don't see Apple Maps in the layer list. It's quite easy to write config files for new map tile services, I did that for Stamen maps which are in the GitHub version of the plugin's addon layers.

But if all you want is one of the Google Maps layers (satellite, map, etc) then Quick Map Services does the job.

Comment: Wow, it is amazing how many layers that Quick Map Services has when you download the Contributed Services as blackgis suggests below, thanks for the tip. Still doesn't answer the question of what happened to Google Maps in OpenLayers, but i guess with the speed of QGIS technology changing, I won't worry about it.

Comment: Look at full list of supported services at https://qms.nextgis.com/. You can add own service easily without github and any packs.