# Resolving Java script Alert that This page was unable to display Google Maps element?

Tags: qgis-2, qgis-openlayers-plugin

Whenever I try to load the Google Hybrid layer on QGIS 1.8.0 and 2.0.1, I get this error:

> This page was unable to display a Google Maps element. Please contact the site administrator. If you are the administrator of this site, please check the JavaScript console or check the following page for troubleshooting: http://g.co/mapsJSApiErrors

How do I correct the error so that the map can load?

Comment: OpenLayers Plugin: Printing and rotating of Javascript API based layers is currently not supported! this is my problem.
what can i do ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please take the short [tour]. This is a little different than other sites - it's a focused Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Please do not use answers to ask additional questions.

Answer (score 4):

I got a key from google and included in each of the GOOGLE html files in the
openlayers plugin html directory... and it started working again.

add your key to the line
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY

Also have to take out the v=3.3 (version) in the current html code.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why that's happening, there seems to be a few posts asking about that.

This post "[Why are the Google basemaps no longer appearing in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172019/why-are-the-google-basemaps-no-longer-appearing-in-qgis)" has a good
solution which allows you to add the Google Tile server as a layer. Uncomment the line for which basemap you want to use and add the file as if it were a Raster layer.

Other suggestions have been to use the QuickMapServices plugin as an alternative.

Other related posts i've seen on SE:
[Google Maps not Showing in QGIS 2.12](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175043/google-maps-not-showing-in-qgis-2-12)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Google has changed the Javascript API to require a key and includes a quota for access  This began June 22, 2016.
https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/standard-plan-2016-update
So this has created an issue for the plugin, I think.  You can debug the error by opening up the Google html files in ./qgis2/python/plugins/openlayers_plugin/html in your browser and looking in the browser console (in Firefox)