# How to display the cartographic background (Google maps) in QGIS 2.18?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I work on QGIS 2.18, unfortunately I cannot display background cartography on this software.

I have the following errors :

[image: First display]
[image: Second display]

```
2017-01-10T12:13:19 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\weblayers\weblayer.py", line 100, in addLayer
            self._addLayerCallback(self)
          File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 158, in addLayer
            self.setMapCrs(coordRefSys)
          File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 206, in setMapCrs
            extMap = coordTrans.transform(extMap, QgsCoordinateTransform.ForwardTransform)
        QgsCsException: Poursuivre la transformation de
        (-0.558505, -12.980715)
        PROJ.4:  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 +to  +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
        Erreur: latitude or longitude exceeded limits

2017-01-10T12:13:32 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\weblayers\weblayer.py", line 100, in addLayer
                self._addLayerCallback(self)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 158, in addLayer
                self.setMapCrs(coordRefSys)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 206, in setMapCrs
                extMap = coordTrans.transform(extMap, QgsCoordinateTransform.ForwardTransform)
            QgsCsException: Poursuivre la transformation de
            (-0.558505, -12.980715)
            PROJ.4:  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 +to  +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
            Erreur: latitude or longitude exceeded limits

2017-01-10T12:13:41 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\weblayers\weblayer.py", line 100, in addLayer
                self._addLayerCallback(self)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 158, in addLayer
                self.setMapCrs(coordRefSys)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 206, in setMapCrs
                extMap = coordTrans.transform(extMap, QgsCoordinateTransform.ForwardTransform)
            QgsCsException: Poursuivre la transformation de
            (-0.558505, -12.980715)
            PROJ.4:  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 +to  +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
            Erreur: latitude or longitude exceeded limits

2017-01-10T12:13:48 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\weblayers\weblayer.py", line 100, in addLayer
                self._addLayerCallback(self)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 158, in addLayer
                self.setMapCrs(coordRefSys)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 206, in setMapCrs
                extMap = coordTrans.transform(extMap, QgsCoordinateTransform.ForwardTransform)
            QgsCsException: Poursuivre la transformation de
            (-0.558505, -12.980715)
            PROJ.4:  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 +to  +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
            Erreur: latitude or longitude exceeded limits

2017-01-10T12:13:55 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\weblayers\weblayer.py", line 100, in addLayer
                self._addLayerCallback(self)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 158, in addLayer
                self.setMapCrs(coordRefSys)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 206, in setMapCrs
                extMap = coordTrans.transform(extMap, QgsCoordinateTransform.ForwardTransform)
            QgsCsException: Poursuivre la transformation de
            (-0.558505, -12.980715)
            PROJ.4:  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 +to  +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
            Erreur: latitude or longitude exceeded limits

2017-01-10T12:15:54 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\weblayers\weblayer.py", line 100, in addLayer
                self._addLayerCallback(self)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 158, in addLayer
                self.setMapCrs(coordRefSys)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 206, in setMapCrs
                extMap = coordTrans.transform(extMap, QgsCoordinateTransform.ForwardTransform)
            QgsCsException: Poursuivre la transformation de
            (-0.558505, -12.980715)
            PROJ.4:  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 +to  +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
            Erreur: latitude or longitude exceeded limits

2017-01-10T12:26:21 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\weblayers\weblayer.py", line 100, in addLayer
                self._addLayerCallback(self)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 158, in addLayer
                self.setMapCrs(coordRefSys)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 206, in setMapCrs
                extMap = coordTrans.transform(extMap, QgsCoordinateTransform.ForwardTransform)
            QgsCsException: Poursuivre la transformation de
            (-0.558505, -12.980715)
            PROJ.4:  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 +to  +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
            Erreur: latitude or longitude exceeded limits

2017-01-10T12:26:44 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\weblayers\weblayer.py", line 100, in addLayer
                self._addLayerCallback(self)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 158, in addLayer
                self.setMapCrs(coordRefSys)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 206, in setMapCrs
                extMap = coordTrans.transform(extMap, QgsCoordinateTransform.ForwardTransform)
            QgsCsException: Poursuivre la transformation de
            (-17.936983, -12.880530)
            PROJ.4:  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 +to  +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
            Erreur: latitude or longitude exceeded limits

2017-01-10T12:37:08 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\weblayers\weblayer.py", line 100, in addLayer
                self._addLayerCallback(self)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 158, in addLayer
                self.setMapCrs(coordRefSys)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 206, in setMapCrs
                extMap = coordTrans.transform(extMap, QgsCoordinateTransform.ForwardTransform)
            QgsCsException: Poursuivre la transformation de
            (-16.046401, -12.880530)
            PROJ.4:  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 +to  +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
            Erreur: latitude or longitude exceeded limits

2017-01-10T12:39:08 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\weblayers\weblayer.py", line 100, in addLayer
                self._addLayerCallback(self)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 158, in addLayer
                self.setMapCrs(coordRefSys)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 206, in setMapCrs
                extMap = coordTrans.transform(extMap, QgsCoordinateTransform.ForwardTransform)
            QgsCsException: Poursuivre la transformation de
            (-16.046401, -12.880530)
            PROJ.4:  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 +to  +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
            Erreur: latitude or longitude exceeded limits

2017-01-10T12:39:16 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\weblayers\weblayer.py", line 100, in addLayer
                self._addLayerCallback(self)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 158, in addLayer
                self.setMapCrs(coordRefSys)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 206, in setMapCrs
                extMap = coordTrans.transform(extMap, QgsCoordinateTransform.ForwardTransform)
            QgsCsException: Poursuivre la transformation de
            (-16.046401, -12.880530)
            PROJ.4:  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 +to  +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
            Erreur: latitude or longitude exceeded limits

2017-01-10T12:43:55 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\weblayers\weblayer.py", line 100, in addLayer
                self._addLayerCallback(self)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 158, in addLayer
                self.setMapCrs(coordRefSys)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 206, in setMapCrs
                extMap = coordTrans.transform(extMap, QgsCoordinateTransform.ForwardTransform)
            QgsCsException: Poursuivre la transformation de
            (-0.558505, -13.445956)
            PROJ.4:  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 +to  +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
            Erreur: latitude or longitude exceeded limits

2017-01-10T12:49:49 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\weblayers\weblayer.py", line 100, in addLayer
                self._addLayerCallback(self)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 158, in addLayer
                self.setMapCrs(coordRefSys)
              File "C:/Users/h.bendechou/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 206, in setMapCrs
                extMap = coordTrans.transform(extMap, QgsCoordinateTransform.ForwardTransform)
            QgsCsException: Poursuivre la transformation de
            (-0.558505, -13.445956)
            PROJ.4:  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 +to  +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
            Erreur: latitude or longitude exceeded limits
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @bendechou! Use the **QuickMapServices** plugin instead as described in this post: [Google Maps not Showing in QGIS 2.12](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175043/google-maps-not-showing-in-qgis-2-12)

Comment: ... or set the **project** CRS to EPSG:3857 before adding the background map.

Comment: Wish we could set an auto reply on stack exchange so that anything mentioning the open layers plugin automatically posts about using quickmapservices instead!